# send arraylist from one to another activity into listview android

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, android-listview

I am making an android app. It is simple and based on quotes. I have a database of around 300 quotes divided in 5 categories (movies, books, etc.) and I show them at random when a user clicks on a category, in a TextView. Now I want the users to have an option to save their favorite quotes, so I have another activity called Favorites where I want the favorites to show in a ListView.

For this I think that the best way is to have all the favorites the user will put in a String ArrayList, and then send the whole ArrayList to the Favorites activity where it will put the strings from the ArrayList in the ListView. But, every time I try to send an ArrayList to the other activity, my app crashes.
I only managed to send the current string that is shown on screen like this

```
text.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            intent.putExtra("key", text.getText());

            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "Added to favorites";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
```

And then I take it and put it in the other activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_favorites);


    final ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    tekst = intent.getStringExtra("key");
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
    lista.setAdapter(adapter);

    listItems.add(tekst);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

But then if I try to add another favorite, it just overwrites the previous one. So how should I deal with this? How to send all the favorites that the user wants to put? Is ArrayList the best option or is there another way?

Comment: save araylist as json string in shared pref and decode the json string into arraylist in next activity and do `setadapter` on listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activity A :

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

intent.putExtra("yourlist", list);
startActivity(intent);
```

Activity B:

```
ArrayList<String> list = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("yourlist");
```

I hope its help you..!

Answer (score 0):

Your previous ArrayList is overwritten because every time you navigate to the Favorites activity, it gets recreated and so does the ArrayList. The data is not persisted. The best option would be to use a database and save the item to the database from one activity. Then the favorite items can be retrieved from the database inside the Favorites activity.